# Alternative way to access environment variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to store production db and email passwords on environment variables to hide to GitHub users.

I set up my vars using `export` command on terminal:

`$ export DB_PASS=mydbpass`

But I can't access via `process.env.DB_PASS`

I'm not sure this is the correct way. I saw that is possible to access by running:

`DB_PASS=mydbpass node server.js`

But I'm looking for a more practical way to do this.

Comment: did you try to set your env var using sudo ?

Comment: sudo doesn't execute export :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's a practical way to do this.**

*First of all, you have ti understand that you have to execute shell file to pass data to Node's [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) objects, i.e, Environment variables.*

Ok, so let's create a `shell` file where you will store all the env variables. Like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export NODE_ENV='development'
export ENVIRONMENT='development'

export PORT='4000'
export TEST_PORT='4040'

# MongoDB
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
```

Let's name this file `env.sh`.

Now let's say your node app is `testApp`  and you run your app by running `npm start`, so this is what you need to do now:

```
testApp~$ . ./env.sh && npm start
```

What above command is doing, it's running your config shell file and then your node app, so in your node app you can access these fields:

```
process.env.PORT
process.env.TEST_PORT // and so on, basically whatever you have in env.sh file
```

I hope everything's clear. Let me know in case of any clarification.